# Estimated labor hours for transmission replacement

Tags: ford, transmission, replace, f-150, book-hours

I have a 2005 f150 fx4 and I just lost reverse, I'm curious as to how many book hours a shop will charge to replace transmission. 
thanks for reading

Comment: Whoever posted this as POB, you need to retract your vote. This is a straightforward question which can be answered objectively. Book hour questions are on-topic for this stack. To the OP ... Welcome to the site. Someone should be able to get you an answer to your question.

Comment: Do you have an automatic or standard shift transmission?

Answer (score 3):

Remove & Replace on an 4x4 Automatic is 6.6hrs. This doesn't include fluid fill or any other maintenance work like the filter so add another .5 hrs or so.

Comment: Sweet, thank you very much for the quick response... btw it's an automatic